In WooCommerce, how do I apply a discount for subscribers only?
My company has an ecommerce website that uses WooCommerce with a number of plug-ins and a LOT of customized code.  Customers can become ‘club members’ with a variety of benefits, for a set monthly fee.   These memberships are handled in WooCommerce as subscriptions.  Right now we want to sell a handful of products with a special price that applies only to subscribers.  That is:
A customer picks Product XYZ and puts it in their cart.  If the customer is not a subscriber, the price they see in the cart is $100.  If they are a subscriber, they get a 10% discount, so the price they see in the cart is $90.
Adding a new plug-in is not in the cards; the site is so heavily customized that any new plug-in risks breaking some existing part of the site.  I am a good PHP programmer, but new to writing WooCommerce custom code.  I think I need an action hook, but where do I put it and how do I check a customer’s subscription status?
